# Changing resolution of rasterbrick using R

Tags: r, resolution, rasterbrick

I have a rasterbrick « env1 » with following informations :

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 3008, 2913, 8762304, 8  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.00331, 0.00207  (x, y)
extent     : -73.38788, -63.74585, 48.13865, 54.36521  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I wanted to change the resolution to have the same x and y with :

```
res(env1)<- 0.00331
```

But went I wanted to plot it, it shows the following error :

> Error in .plotraster2(obj, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, xaxt =
> xa,  :  no values associated with this RasterLayer

Is there any way to change the resolution in order to have the same x and y?

Comment: In this case, to not end up with an empty raster, you would have to resample your data but, for future reference, to change the x and y resolution of a raster array you would use `res(x) <- c(0.00331, 0.00331)`

Answer (score 5):

The function you are looking for is rather `resample`, `res` is rather used to *set* a resolution: if used to change an existing one, outputs an empty raster ; in the following example, a dummy raster is built with the extent and crs of the first one, but with the desired resolution:

```
library(raster)
r1 = raster()
r2 = raster(extent(r1), resolution = 0.00331, crs = crs(r1))
r3 = resample(r1, r2)
```

Comment: It does change the resolution of the array but does not resample the data so, you end up with a raster that has no values.